# ODE23 Matlab to Python

Tags: python, matlab, matrix, ode

I have the following code in MATLAB,

```matlab
n = 5;
ainit = zeros(1,n); 
    for i=1:ndof
            ainit(i) = 0; 
    end
    
binit = zeros(1,ndof); 
disp(binit)
x0 = [ainit,binit];

tf = 10; step = .001; tspan = 0:step:tf
funky=@(t,x) A*x + BF; %beam(t,x,K,M,wns,psi2,Load);
[t2,q2] = ode23(funky,tspan, x0, []);
```

where `A` is a *n x n* square matrix and `BF` is a *n x 1* vector

I am trying to convert this code into Python. So far I have as follows,

```py
y0 = np.zeros((4*n))
Time_Step = np.arange(0, 10, 0.001)
func = lambda x, t: (A*x+BF)
q = scipy.integrate.solve_ivp(func, Time_Step, y0)
```

This gives me an error that states `could not broadcast input array from shape (20,20) into shape (20,)`

How can I translate MATLAB's `ode23` to Python?

Comment: `*` is the element-wise multiplication, with broadcast where the dimensions don't fit. The operator for matrix multiplication is `@`. Or use the `numpy.dot` or `numpy.matmult` procedures. // Is `BF` really a square matrix?

Comment: @LutzLehmann, you correctly identified the mistake in my proposed question which I have since resolved. `Bf` is an `n, 1` matrix (apologies for that mistake).  After switching the `*` to `@` and running the code I received a value error stating `matmul: Input operand 1 does not have enough dimensions (has 0, gufunc core with signature (n?,k),(k,m?)->(n?,m?) requires 1)`

Comment: There is not enough information. It seems that the factor `A` got changed to a simple float? Use some debugging method to observe the actual content of `A` during the integration.

Comment: @LutzLehmann I changed the syntax in the from `func = lambda x, t: (A@x+BF)` to `func = lambda t, x: (A@x+BF)` which from the documentation seems like the correct way. This threw the error from before `could not broadcast input array from shape (20,20) into shape (20,).`

Comment: Then it now depends on what the format of `A` and `BF` is. If you add a row and a column vector, then you may get an error or it gets broadcast into a square matrix. The easiest way would be to ensure that the returned result is again a flat array, using `flatten` or `hstack` or `reshape` or `concatenate`.

Comment: @LutzLehmann wouldnt reshaping `A` (square matrix) and `BF` (vector) change the physical relation between the two. For example, `func = lambda t, x: np.ndarray.flatten(A@x) + np.ndarray.flatten(B)` produces an output but the values are incorrect.

Comment: Wrong in a single evaluation or after integration? How is `A` constructed, is it an ndarray or a matrix type? Could you for some reason have ended up with the transpose matrix? Note that Matlab is column-first while Numpy is row-first.

Comment: @LutzLehmann, After double checking my matrices against my MATLAB code I can confirm they are the same to approx. 10 decimal places (and aren't transposed). `A` is a `numpy.ndarray` and is constructed from the formula  `A = [[ 0, I (n,n identity matrix) ], [ -M^-1*K, -M^-1*C]] ` but regardless the  `A ` and  `BF ` Matricies are equivalent. The issue still lies in trying to solve it in the same way ODE23 does.

Answer (score 0):

**Related to question: How can I translate MATLAB's ode23 to Python?**

By default the [scipy.integrate.solve_ivp](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.solve_ivp.html) uses the method Runge-Kutta of order 5(4). If you want to use a method like ode23 you have to specify the method in the arguments:

```
q = scipy.integrate.solve_ivp(func, Time_Step, y0, method='RK23')
```

**Related to question: Error could not broadcast input array from shape (20,20) into shape (20,)**

I think that the comment of @Lutz Lehmann is in the correct way.

Comment: The actual method isn't in question, though of course you do need to specify you're using ode23. It's the shape of the input arguments that is the error. That needs to be fixed first.

Comment: Hey JosSan, thanks for the suggestion! However, when defining the method = 'RK23' I get the same error 'could not broadcast input array from shape (20,20) into shape (20,).'